# Vscode: Changing the color of filename in searchbar

Tags: visual-studio-code, customization

I am searching across many files in my local repo. But the search results and the filenames are all the same color. Is there any way to make the filename color change for better readability?

I'm using a theme called Cobalt2
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the color or style of those filenames, see [Better formatting in sidebar search](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/135275) - it is on the backlog.  You should upvote that issue.

Since it looks like you are already viewing it as a tree, rather than list, which helps a bit, your only other option is to click on the `Open in Editor` button which does a much better job of displaying the filenames - they are underlined with empty lines between.  Try it.

[image: search editor image]

Comment: too bad, sounds like it would be a pretty useful feature, imho